# faces/index.xhtml location in java web application

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee

In ***web.xml***, I had found the declaration for the initial web page as follows.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Where is ***face*** in Java Web application? I have known that ***index.xhtml*** is located in ***Web Pages*** folder.

[image]

Comment: `/faces`, `*.jsf` and `*.faces` are automatically mapped by [`FacesServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html). "*If the runtime determines that the Servlet must be automatically mapped, it must be mapped to the following `<url-pattern>` entries - `/faces`, `*.jsf`, `*.faces`.*" Thus, they are implicit in case `FacesServlet` is not explicitly registered  (which happens, if certain criteria meet as specified in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

if you opened web.xml you will find mapping of /faces/* url to servlet that contain life cycle of JSF and managed by that servlet

as any page goes in JSF life cycle must be under/faces/

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```